# change the .exe file icon in pkg library

Tags: node.js, npm

I have mean stack app to create executable file by using npm pkg. It converted successfully (and is running too). After changing icon and version of .exe file using rcedit library or resource hacker,  file is not running properly and it throws an error like `pkg: Error reading from file`

Please guide me to change icon of .exe file

Comment: Please anybody knows this error help me

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`node-recedit`](https://github.com/electron/node-rcedit) for editing Windows Executable.

Example:

```js
const rcedit = require('rcedit')

await rcedit("./myExecutable.exe", {
  icon: "./myIcon.ico"
})
```

here `myExecutable.exe` should be replaced by path to your `.exe` file, and `myIcon.ico` is the icon you want to use in `.ico` format.

**Note** - rcedit only works for windows executables.

Comment: There is a typo in the code: it should be `await` instead of `async`. This code would result in a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Also, this code does not fix the issue. The executable still crashes on startup with _Pkg: Error reading from file_ (for me, at least). Any fixes yet?

Comment: updated the syntax, maybe because rcedit restructures some data it crashes when trying to read the file.

Comment: Yes, especially since Resource Hacker does the same thing. Rcedit must be doing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with this. I solved the issue using `npm install --save-dev resedit`. This one does not damage the final exe. This package does not require wine installed to work with Linux, which is also better than some other resource editors.

[This project](https://github.com/AngaBlue/exe) automates this process using `resedit` without problems. You can use it as a reference to build your own script to customize the exe icon and properties.

Answer (score -1):

You need to using pkg version 4.3.6.

Comment: Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: @Mahmoud Run `npm install -g pkg@4.3.6`